# Como encontrar o valor mais comum dentro de cada coluna de uma matriz utilizando python?

Tags: python, matriz

Eu tenho uma matriz (3 x 3280), eu preciso percorrer cada coluna e consequentemente cada linha e encontrar o valor mais frequente e assim gerar outro vetor (1 x 3280) com esses valores. Por exemplo:

```
matriz=[1 2 3 4 ....],[2 3 4 5....],[1 2 4 4...]]
```

para a primeira coluna, percorrendo as três linhas tem-se `[1 2 1]`, então valor mais comum é 1. Para a segunda coluna percorrendo as três linhas `[2 3 2]` então valor mais comum é 2.

Eu tentei fazer um código no Python, mas como eu não sei nada de Python dá muito erros.

Comment: Você sabe alguma outra linguagem? Por quê Python?

Comment: Coloque o código que já tem para conseguirmos perceber as suas dúvidas e ajudar-lhe a progredir.

Comment: Anderson, porque o resto do programa está em python, essa parte da duvida é cerca de 1/3 do codigo, o resto está feito e certo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma semelhante ao que o [Vitor Hugo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/303733/5878) postou em sua resposta, basta calcular a matriz transposta e verificar o elemento mais comum de cada linha; a lógica é exatamente a que ele utilizou, mas é possível fazê-la de uma maneira mais simples:

```
def most_common_of_columns(matrix):
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        most_commons = Counter(column).most_common(1)
        yield most_commons[0][0]
```

Onde `zip(*matrix)` retorna a matriz transposta; `Counter(column).most_common(1)` retorna uma lista com o par (número, quantidade) do número mais comum e, finalmente, `most_commons[0][0]` retorna o número mais comum.

Assim, fazer algo como:

```
matrix = [
    [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,9,8], 
    [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
    [1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,4,4]
]

print(list(most_common_of_columns(m)))
```

Retornará: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 9, 8]`, que são os elementos mais comuns de cada coluna. Repare que, se não houver um elemento mais comum, será retornado o elemento da primeira linha.

Comment: Entendi... muito obrigada pessoal!!!! ajudou!!

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o procedimento que você descreve, basicamente precisara do tipo `Counter` encontrado na lib `collections` e da função `zip`, nativa do python. Primeiro irei colar o código de exemplo e ao final irei explicado.

```
from collections import Counter

m = [
    [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,9,8], 
    [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
    [1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,4,4]
]

inversa = []
contadores = []
resultado = []

for x in zip(m[0],m[1],m[2]):
    inversa.append(list(x))


for x in inversa:
    a = Counter(x)
    b = a.most_common(1)
    contadores.append(b)


for x in contadores:
    a = x[0]
    b = a[0]
    resultado.append(b)

print(resultado)
```

Começamos os trabalhos importando o `Counter` e definindo a matriz de trabalho. Para fins didáticos defini uma matriz 3 por 10, mas não se preocupe, pode aumentar seu tamanho e o código ainda irá funcionar.

Após isso defini também três listas auxiliares, sendo que estas serão explicadas ao longo do código.

A primeira coisa a fazer é obter a inversa (Matematicamente, o termo correto é **transposta**) da matriz inserida, pois isso facilitará nosso trabalho. Fazemos isso usando um **for loop** que percorre todos os termos da lista de tuplas retornadas da função **zip** e salva cada tupla como uma linha da lista inversa.

se você interrompesse o código ai e desse um **print** em **inversa** veria algo como:

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 3],
 [3, 4, 4],
 [4, 5, 4],
 [5, 6, 4],
 [9, 7, 4],
 [8, 8, 4]]
```

Após isso usamos mais um **for loop** para correr todas as linhas da matriz inversa(que são as colunas de nossa matriz original) e usamos o *Counter* para contar o número de repetições de cada termo.

**Ainda dentro do nosso for loop** usamos o método **most_common** acompanhado do parâmetro **1** para obter o termo mais comum de cada linha e salvamos as tuplas resultantes desse loop na lista **contadores**.

Se você parasse o código aqui e desse um **print** em **contadores** veria algo como:

```
[[(1, 3)], [(1, 2)], [(1, 2)], [(1, 2)], [(3, 2)], [(4, 2)], [(4, 2)], [(4, 1)], [(9, 1)], [(8, 2)]]
```

Sendo que para cada coluna de nossa matriz temos um `[(x, y)]` sendo que `x` representa o termo mais repetido e `y` a quantidade de vezes que este se repetiu.

Por fim, corremos todas as tuplas da lista de contadores, salvamos em `a` o primeiro campo de cada linha (este paço é necessário pois apesar de ser uma lista de tuplas com apenas um componente, ainda é uma lista).

**Ainda dentro do loop final**, salvamos em `b` o primeiro termo dentro de `a`, pois é o termo mais repetido que nos interteça, e não quantas vezes ele se repetiu. 
Sendo que por fim colocamos todos os valores de `b` dentro da lista resultados e exibimos esta.

Ao fim do código você terá esse resultado:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 9, 8]
```

Sendo a lista resultados o vetor composto pelos termos mais comuns :)

Comment: Um detalhe (que não é detalhe): matriz inversa é diferente de matriz transposta. O que você obteve foi a transposta, não inversa.

Comment: Realmente, usei o termo matemático incorreto. Me referi a matriz inversa pela logica de inverter posições, não pela matemática em si.
De qualquer forma, vou alterar a pergunta, mas não excluir o termo, para que quem chegue até o final entenda a lógica de seu comentário.

Comment: Vitor Hugo muito obrigada pela sua resposta!!!!